# Dividing and Modulus in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm creating an ALU in verilog just for the purpose of simulation. But I can't figure out how to divide two 16 bit inputs. A regular `A=B/C` doesn't work (where B,C is a `input[15:0]` and A is `output reg[15:0]`). Similarly with `A=B%C`.

Would I have to separately implement a division circuit module? I understand division is a very complex operation and that would be the actual way to do it but I'm only doing it for simulation. Is there no shorter way to divide two 16bit inputs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division in verilog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725657/division-in-verilog)

Comment: Those operations should work fine in simulation, and possibly even for synthesis, 16 bits may be manageable. What do you mean that it 'doesn't work'?

Comment: By that I mean it just doesn't work. If I'm doing `out1=in1/in2`, I get out1=0 and `out2=in1%in2`, I get out2= the value of in2, invariably.

Comment: 'It just doesn't work' isn't very helpful - post some code that compiles but which produces an unexpected result.

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/pYEF2UN1

And the output is ` 0in1=15 | in2= 4 | out1= x | out2= x
                  10in1= 8 | in2= 3 | out1= x | out2= x`

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently does this:

```
initial begin
  out1=in1/in2; out2=in1%in2;
end
```

This doesn't do anything - the `initial` block runs through once at the start of simulation, when `in1` and `in2` are `X`'s, setting `out1` and `out2` to X, and then stopping. Change your logic to:

```
   always
      @* begin
         out1=in1/in2; 
         out2=in1%in2;
      end
```

This executes every time `in1` or `in2` changes.